# react native iOS app failed with XPC connection interrupted error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I just run my react native app in Xcode 11.3.1 after pod installs I got the error for "Flipper" so I used a solution and commented on all the flipper functions from the pod file.
Now I run my code and I am getting the below error:

```
2020-12-22 18:44:41.631102+0530 dotcom[32210:301250] XPC connection interrupted
```

I am not an iOS developer so if anyone resolved a similar issue or can help me with this please share the answer here. I am stuck with this issue.

Note: I newly updated the Mac and Xcode too.

I can see only the splash screen of my project nothing else.

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you Archive in debug scheme.

1. Open sheme popup in Xcode (Shift + Command + , )
2. In the left pane, select Archive
3. Build Configuration : select Release (if it is Debug)